# .NET - Unicode character at the end of the sorting order

Tags: .net, sorting, unicode, collation

I am hoping there is a character that I can use to put a string as the last item when sorted in a list. Note this does not have to be bullet proof, but considering e.g. `+,_,(` etc are usually used to put a string before text (in ASCII/NTFS etc) is there a character I can use to put a string at the end?

Comment: Unicode does not define an "always last" codepoint.  U+3fffff is attractive, but it is not a character.  Don't do this.

Comment: @HansPassant How did you get 3FFFFF? Isn't the (numerically) last valid codepoint 10FFFF since there are 16 astral planes?

Comment: If I was to limit this to normal ASCII characters, then is `z` last? Or is there any after?

Comment: Can you use a custom comparer?

Comment: @Simon The (numerically) last ASCII char is 7F. Of normal printable characters `~` is at 7E. But if you use culture aware sorting the order might differ.

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes that would be my second option, but Im lazy and this method is not going to cause any problems

Comment: @CodesInChaos and i think 7F is the tilde `~`. but this seems to be sorted before `A-z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying this:

```
Char.ConvertFromUtf32(int.MaxValue);
```

gives:

> A valid UTF32 value is between 0x000000 and 0x10ffff, inclusive, and
>   should not include surrogate codepoint values (0x00d800 ~ 0x00dfff).

Then I guess what you need is something like:

```
Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x10ffff);
```

Comment: Looking for Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x10ffff); in Google gives
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849259/c-sharp-highest-string

Comment: Thanks, I found out that I could not use a custom sorter, so this mehod worked